# How to get total MB downloaded in network monitor in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I want to monitor my app network usage in MB's during downloading batch of data for offline use.  There is app `TrafficMonitor` from @commonsguy but I need close look using Android Studio tools

Android Studio `monitor>network` only shows `Tx` Transmit Bytes and `Rx` Receive Bytes.
It's look like `network monitor` is missing essential functionality.

Is there any way to get app usage in particular interval using `network monitor` or any other way arround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try NetworkStatsManager .

```
            NetworkStats queryDetailsForUid (int networkType, 
            String subscriberId, 
            long startTime, 
            long endTime, 
            int uid)
```

[Refer this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager.html)

Comment: @Qamar try once